# How to improve MacOS SwiftUI Picker performance

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

In an ongoing exercise of migrating a small form app from UIKit to SwiftUI I have encountered a significant performance difference between UIKit PopUpButton and SwiftUI Picker.  It is a Picker with a longish list (433 items - ISO639 language list).  Under UIKit the PopUpButton opens instantly to all intents and purposes. Under SwiftUI the picker is taking 4-5 seconds from click to list being presented.  Sufficiently long for the spinning beachball to appear.

I am guessing that it is dynamically creating the subview of items after the mouse click.  Has anyone experience with long picker lists and encountered performance issues?  I did an experiment with unrolling the ForEach loop that the picker is built from into a view with Groups within Groups within Groups (that did work) ....however, it took fractionally longer.

The PickerView is

```
struct ISO639Picker: View {
  @Binding var selection: ISO639LanguageCode
  var body: some View {
    Picker("", selection: $selection) {
      ForEach(codeSet.codes) { code in
        Text(code.alpha3B).tag(code)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For completeness, codeSet is a global instance of Class that populates from an ISO639 text source and it is instantiated at app startup.  The "codes" member is an array of structures as below.

```
public struct ISO639LanguageCode: Hashable,Identifiable {
  public var id = UUID()
  public var alpha3B: String
  public var alpha3T: String
  public var alpha2: String
  public var name: String
  public var family: String
}
```

Any suggestions on where the performance issue may be would be appreciated.

Comment: "significant performance difference between UIKit PopUpButton and SwiftUI Picker"  `NSPopupButton` with UIKit?  What is your definition of UIKit?

Comment: OK, I *really* meant Cocoa, etc, with IB for MacOS.  Just seeing so many UIKit references, it gets embedded in the fingers.  The real issue being that a Picker with 400+ items is taking 4-5 seconds to display  on my Mac.

Comment: I've tested similar code that you show, a picker(wheel)  with an array of "ISO639LanguageCode" objects,
containing thousands of entries without any problems.
On macos 12.beta, xcode 13.beta, target ios 15 and macCatalyst.

Comment: Thanks for doing a trial. I am confined to the MacOS 10.15.7 world due to hardware, so perhaps it is just an issue that I will have to live with until I upgrade hardware.

Comment: Could you clarify what platforms you’re using? Is it UIKit+Catalyst? Is the SwiftUI also Catalyst or is it an AppKit app?

Comment: I’m not seeing any performance issues on macOS 11 either. If you need to support 10.15, I’d recommend wrapping NSPopupButton in NSViewRepresentable.

Comment: The platform is MacBook Pro (Late 2012), OS 10.15.7.  The app is a MacOS Document App, SwiftUI Interface, and Life Cycle of AppKit App Delegate, I think that covers the all the parameters 8-).

Comment: I will investigate wrapping an NSPopupButton.  I already have the code to create the NSPopupButton.  So, hopefully, a straightforeward exercise for later on today.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I experimented with setting the picker style to Segmented and RadioGroup (the only ones available in 10.15).  In  both cases, the delay is similar but shifted to the view that contains the picker.  Now since the control is fully presented in the view with those styles, it would appear to confirm that the delay is in the building of the picker.  The Popup style on being built and presented on the Tap Gesture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone encountering the same issue, the resolution, for me, is to use Adams' suggestion of an NSPopupButton wrapped in an NSViewRepresentable.  It took a while to determine the right notification to hook up with.  An implementation that is sufficient for my needs is offered below;

```
struct NSPopUpButtonView<ItemType>: NSViewRepresentable where ItemType:Equatable {
  @Binding var selection: ItemType
  var popupCreator: () -> NSPopUpButton
  
  typealias NSViewType = NSPopUpButton
  
  func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<NSPopUpButtonView>) -> NSPopUpButton {
    let newPopupButton = popupCreator()
    setPopUpFromSelection(newPopupButton, selection: selection)
    return newPopupButton
  }
  
  func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSPopUpButton, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<NSPopUpButtonView>) {
    setPopUpFromSelection(nsView, selection: selection)
  }
  
  func setPopUpFromSelection(_ button:NSPopUpButton, selection:ItemType)
  {
    let itemsList = button.itemArray
    let matchedMenuItem = itemsList.filter{($0.representedObject as! ItemType) == selection}.first
    if matchedMenuItem != nil
    {
      button.select(matchedMenuItem)
    }
  }
  
  func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(self)
  }
  
  class Coordinator:NSObject {
    var parent: NSPopUpButtonView!
    
    init(_ parent: NSPopUpButtonView)
    {
      super.init()
      self.parent = parent
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                             selector: #selector(dropdownItemSelected),
                                             name: NSMenu.didSendActionNotification,
                                             object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func dropdownItemSelected(_ notification: NSNotification)
    {
      let menuItem = (notification.userInfo?["MenuItem"])! as! NSMenuItem
      parent.selection = menuItem.representedObject as! ItemType
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found coercing a [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu) to behave like a Picker to be more performant.

```
Menu {
    ForEach(codeSet.codes) { code in
        Button("\(code.alpha3B)", action: { self.selection = code })
    }
} label: {
    Text("\(self.selection.alpha3B)")
}
```